How do I clear the OpenStreetMap tile layer in the TWebLeafletMaps component?
I have a TWebLeafletMaps component from TMS WEB Core that is placed on my form and it loads an OpenStreetMap by default.
I don't seem to have any control over this. It just loads OpenStreetMap by default according to my Options property on the component.
How can remove or clear this default OpenStreetMap tile layer?
I just want a clean blank leaflet map with nothing on it.
